# awk numbers extraction length

Tags: awk, numbers, extract, maxlength

I am unable to catch numbers from file1 from column $3, where should be met condition, that just only numbers in length of exact 8 numbers before underscore or after underscore are extracted.

This below doesn't work. Only 2nd is a bit close to solution:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]{8}/,"",$3) && $22 = substr($3,1,8)}1' file1
awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$3) && $3 = substr($3,1,8)}1' file1
```

file1:

```
44446464654 field 2020135_7777_5x_definition
49989798797 mach 202013_7777_a5_19800511
498797877 pat math_200418_memo05874_12345678
44444 def math_200418_memo05874789_12345678
5659 explaination 28008874_memo
5659 explaination _28008874_memo
```

Needed output:

```
49989798797 mach 19800511
498797877 pat 12345678
44444 def 12345678
5659 explaination 28008874
5659 explaination 28008874
```

Comment: should be this considered as correct?

awk 'match($3, /_([[:digit:]]{8})_*/, a) {print $1,$2,a[1]}' file1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk. Split last field (`$NF`) with `_` in an array and use a for loop with its elements. In every loop check content of current element with a regex.

```
awk '{split($NF,array,"_"); for(i in array) { if(array[i]~/^[0-9]{8}$/) { print $1,$2,array[i]; next } } }' file
```

Output:

```
49989798797 mach 19800511
498797877 pat 12345678
44444 def 12345678
5659 explaination 28008874
5659 explaination 28008874
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: your ones showing even if string in column $3 is alphabed of 8chars it will be printed, could that be  limited just for digits?

Comment: I updated my answer 9 minutes ago. I replaced `length(array[i])==8` with `array[i]~/^[0-9]{8}$/`.